# Avoid overriding htaccess in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following code in htaccess.

```
# BEGIN Wordpress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Add this line
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    !/document         [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]

# Add these lines
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !search\.php         [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /document/([^/]+)/?  [NC]
RewriteRule .*  /wordpress/search.php?id=%1      [L,NC]

</IfModule>
# END Wordpress
```

Lines under #Add this/these line(s) are my custom code which are used to redirect any URL like `http://example.com/document/123` to `http://example.com/search.php?id=123`.

Now I want to revise this code to avoid my custom rules been overriden by WordPress after update/installing WordPress/plugins.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move your second additional block to before the WordPress section. The `[L]` flag in your rewrite rule should prevent any of the remaining conditions and rules from being evaluated. You won't need your first added line.

```
# Your additions
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !search\.php         [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /document/([^/]+)/?  [NC]
RewriteRule .*  /wordpress/search.php?id=%1      [L,NC]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN Wordpress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END Wordpress
```